# Getting TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple. How to fix it?

Tags: python, nlp

I am writing the following two functions:

```
def sent_transform(sent_string):
    stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    tokens = word_tokenize(sent_string)
    tokens = [stemmer.stem(token.lower()) for token in tokens]
    tokens = ['num' if token.translate({ord(c): None for c in ",.-"}).isdigit() else token for token in tokens]
    return tokens

def make_ngram_tuples(samples):
    def get_ngram(i):
        if 2 > 1:
         return (tuple([samples[i-j] for j in range(2-1,0,-1)]),samples[i])
    return map(get_ngram,range(2-1,len(samples)))

class BiGramModel:
    def __init__(self, trainfiles):
        self.trainfiles=trainfiles
        wordlist = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', self.trainfiles)
        self.wordlist = Counter(wordlist)
        self.list1=[]
        for word, count in self.wordlist.items():
            if count == 1:
                self.trainfiles = re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(word), '<unk>', self.trainfiles)
                self.list1.append('<unk>')
            else:
                self.list1.append(word)
        self.l2=list(set(self.list1))
        print self.l2
        print self.trainfiles
        self.m = [' '.join(i) for s2 in self.trainfiles.split('.') for i in zip(s2.split(),s2.split()[1:])]
        print self.m


   def logprob(self,context,event):
        str = context + " " + event
        list=[]
        list.append(str)
        c1 = self.m.count(str)
        v=len(self.l2)

        c2=self.trainfiles.count(context)
        c3=(c1+1.0)/(c2+v)
        self.prob=math.log(c3,2)
        return self.prob

   def getppl(self, testfile):
        ppl = 0.0
        t = 0.0
        with open(testfile) as f:
            text = f.read()

        sentences = re.split(r' *[\.\?!][\'"\)\]]* *', text)
        print sentences
        for sentence in sentences:
            tokens = sent_transform(sentence)
            l = make_ngram_tuples(tokens)
            for p in l:
                t += 1
                ppl += self.logprob(p[0], p[1])
        return math.pow(2, -ppl/t)

   def main():
       bi=BiGramModel("STOP to be or not to be STOP")
       l = bi.getppl("/Users/abc/Desktop/example.txt")
       print l
   main()
```

sent_transform stems the sentences and replaces numbers with token , and make_ngram_tuples makes its grams, but when I run it I get the following error:

EDIT: Getting this error now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abc/Downloads/stanford-corenlp-2012-07-09/code.py", line 133, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/abc/Downloads/stanford-corenlp-2012-07-09/code.py", line 131, in main
    l = bi.getppl("/Users/abc/Desktop/example.txt")
  File "/Users/abc/Downloads/stanford-corenlp-2012-07-09/code.py", line 121, in getppl
    ppl += self.logprob(p[0], p[1])
  File "/Users/abc/Downloads/stanford-corenlp-2012-07-09/code.py", line 88, in logprob
    str = context + " " + event
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

How to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`sent_transform` should *return* tokens, not `print` tokens.

```
def sent_transform(sent_string):
    stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    tokens = word_tokenize(sent_string)
    tokens = [stemmer.stem(token.lower()) for token in tokens]
    tokens = ['num' if token.translate({ord(c): None for c in ",.-"}).isdigit() else token for token in tokens]
    return tokens
```

As written, `sent_transform` will always *return* `None`<sup>1</sup> which means that `tokens` is `None` in `getppl`.  That gets passed to `make_ngram_tuples` as `samples` which results in the exception you're seeing when you try to get the length of `samples`.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Functions with no return value always return `None`.</sup>

Comment: Hi @mgilson, I edited my function, when I do return it gives me the following error.

Comment: @MarthaPears -- One question at a time.  Programming is often like whack-a-mole.  The key here is to learn how to read the traceback.  It says "Can't concatenate a string and a tuple".  Ok.  That means that either `context` is a tuple or `event` is.  Try to figure out _why_ that is the case by walking back through your code.

Comment: I went through, can't figure out how to fix it. Any ideas how to fix it?